# ClassCast Exception in java

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql

Iam writing a query in hibernate and my method is:

```
public String a(Object[] selectedAlarmId,
            Object[] selecteddeviceID, String loggedInUser, String clientIp,
            String role) throws Exception {
        int result = 0;
        b grp = new b();
        try {

            Session hiberSession = HibernateSessionFactory.currentSession();
            Transaction transaction = hiberSession.beginTransaction();

            List deviceQueryList = null;

            String clauseAppender = ("select max(severity),devicenodeid  from AlarmMappingBean where devicenodeid in (:devicelist) group by devicenodeid");
            Query deviceQuery = hiberSession.createQuery(clauseAppender);
            deviceQuery.setParameterList("devicelist", selecteddeviceID);
            deviceQueryList = deviceQuery.list();
            Iterator<Object[]> iter = deviceQueryList.iterator();

            while(iter.hasNext()){              
                Object[] objAlarm = iter.next();
                System.out.println(objAlarm.length);
                System.out.println("Severity - > " + objAlarm[0]);
                System.out.println("Device Node ID - > " + objAlarm[1]);            
                Query updateMangedNode = hiberSession
                .createQuery("update ManagedNode  set highestSeverity =? where nodeId = ?");
                updateMangedNode.setParameter(0, objAlarm[0]);
                updateMangedNode.setParameter(1, Long.parseLong(objAlarm[1].toString()));               
                //updateMangedNode.executeUpdate();
            }
        //  Long[] deviceArray =(Long[]) selecteddeviceID; 
        Exception occurs here-->    Object[] devArray = (Long[]) selecteddeviceID;


            Query groupQuery = hiberSession
                    .createQuery("select groupId from b where nodeId in (:devicelist)");

              groupQuery.setParameterList("devicelist", devArray);

            List<ManagedNode> devicelist = new ArrayList<ManagedNode>();
            devicelist = groupQuery.list();
            if(!(devicelist.isEmpty() )){
            Iterator<ManagedNode> itergroup =devicelist.iterator(); 
            while(itergroup.hasNext()){
                ManagedNode objgroup = itergroup.next();                
                grp.updateGroupHighestSeverity(objgroup.getGroupId());
            }


            }
            transaction.commit();


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw e;
        } finally {
            HibernateSessionFactory.closeSession();
        }
        return Integer.toString(result);
    }
```

Here the selecteddeviceId has values as [1234,12345, null, null]
and query from the table b "select groupid from b where nodeid in(devicelist)" here datatype of groupid is int and nodeid is long

> It is giving me classcast exception as Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be
>   cast to [Ljava.lang.Long;

I am using `PostgresSQl`

Please help

Comment: selectedDeviceID sounds like a single long to me, not an array. And you should change the initialize from object[] selectedDeviceID to long[]

Comment: As a general comment (and not addressing your immediate problem, so this is _not_ an answer) I advise trying to put the logging and transaction management in aspects if you can, as that lets you boil that rather-long method down to something that's just doing “real” work. I find that makes code much easier to read and understand.

Answer (score 1):

From your code: `Object[] devArray = (Long[]) selecteddeviceID;`

Why are you casting it to Long[] if you need to assign selecteddeviceID, which is already a Object[], to Object[]?

Try doing this instead

```
 Long[] devArray = Arrays.copyOf(selecteddeviceID, selecteddeviceID.length, Long[].class)
```

Comment: from the query nodeId is long so the devicelist ie the selecteddeviceId should also be long,, so i am trying to convert the object array to long

Comment: Also is it correct to convert to Object to long as did in the code??

Comment: java.lang.ArrayStoreException..i am getting this exception

Comment: Type of your value is not Long, you cannot store some other object to the Long array.

Comment: selectedeviceid coantains [1,2,3,null,null,null,null]..hw do i convert this into long??

Comment: Are you sure 1, 2 and 3 are stored as Long and not as Integer? Verify it using isntanceof.