# ClassCastException in karaf only after restart

Tags: java, osgi, apache-karaf, osgi-bundle, karaf

I have a two Bundles A of version 05.18.000  which uses B of 05.18.000 used in Bundle C.

and I have same bundles A and B of different version 05.20.000 used in Bundle D.

Bundle A is trying to cast a concrete class to an interface. Both the interface and implementation classes are in Bundle B.

When I am using both C and D both at runtime they are working fine.

But when I restart the karaf container, a class cast Exception is thrown in Bundle A.

```
@Override
public String parse(DeviceMessageEnvelope deviceMessageEnvelope) {

    String result = "NO RESULTS";
    LOGGER.debug("HL7MinaServerParserControllerBase.parse called.");
    try {
        HL7MinaServerCommunicationObject commObject = getHL7MinaServerCommunicationObject();

        commObject.initObject((MinaServerCom) getDeviceCom(), deviceMessageEnvelope, getParser());

        LOGGER.debug("HL7MinaServerParserControllerBase: Attempted to connect device com");
        boolean connected = getDeviceCom().connect();

        if (connected) {
            while (commObject.isRunning()) {
                LOGGER.debug("HL7MinaServerParserControllerBase.parse : In Loop isRunning() : " + commObject.isRunning());
                Thread.sleep(getWaitTime());
            }
            LOGGER.debug("HL7MinaServerParserControllerBase.parse : Exit from while commObject.isRunning()");
            result = commObject.getResult();
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        LOGGER.warn("HL7MinaServerParserControllerBase.parse :  Error in HL7MinaServerParserControllerBase", e);
    } catch (CommunicationException e) {
        LOGGER.warn("HL7MinaServerParserControllerBase.parse :  Error in HL7MinaServerParserControllerBase", e);
    } catch (MinaSupportConfigurationException e) {
        LOGGER.warn("HL7MinaServerParserControllerBase.parse :  Error in HL7MinaServerParserControllerBase", e);
    } finally {
        try {
            getDeviceCom().release();
        } catch (CommunicationException e) {
            LOGGER.warn("HL7MinaServerParserControllerBase : Error trying to release the com", e);
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Below is the error:

```
[2018-03-01 22:46:38.287] [Device Id: 10237 Device Name : WA_CMS_GW] ERROR com.company.driver.factory.DeviceTask                            com.company.drvs.sdk.mina.com.server.types.MinaServerComImpl cannot be cast to com.company.drvs.sdk.mina.com.server.MinaServerCom
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.company.drvs.sdk.mina.com.server.types.MinaServerComImpl cannot be cast to com.company.drvs.sdk.mina.com.server.MinaServerCom
    at com.company.drvs.sdk.mina.com.server.types.parser.HL7MinaServerParserControllerBase.parse(HL7MinaServerParserControllerBase.java:43)[411:com.company.drvs.sdk.company-sdk-mina-support-hl7:5.20.0]
    at com.company.drvs.welchallyn.nce.parser.NCEParserController.getResult(NCEParserController.java:57)[412:com.company.drvs.welchallyn-nce.core:1.0.1]
    at com.company.drvs.welchallyn.nce.parser.NCEParserController.parse(NCEParserController.java:45)[412:com.company.drvs.welchallyn-nce.core:1.0.1]
    at com.company.drvs.welchallyn.nce.driver.Driver.execute(Driver.java:67)[412:com.company.drvs.welchallyn-nce.core:1.0.1]
    at com.company.driver.factory.DeviceTask.execute(DeviceTask.java:46)[321:com.company.dxc.DriverHarness:1.10.1.GA]
    at com.company.task.CycleTaskHarness.run(CycleTaskHarness.java:88)[312:com.company.dxc.TaskRunner:1.10.1.GA]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)[:1.8.0_161]
[2018-03-01 22:46:38.287] [Device Id: 10237 Device Name : WA_CMS_GW] WARN  com.company.task.CycleTaskHarness                                Task retry: Device Id: 10237 Device Name : WA_CMS_GW, com.company.task.TaskException: com.company.drvs.sdk.mina.com.server.types.MinaServerComImpl cannot be cast to com.company.drvs.sdk.mina.com.server.MinaServerCom
[2018-03-01 22:46:38.287] [Device Id: 10237 Device Name : WA_CMS_GW] ERROR com.company.task.CycleTaskHarness                                Task error:
com.company.task.TaskException: com.company.drvs.sdk.mina.com.server.types.MinaServerComImpl cannot be cast to com.company.drvs.sdk.mina.com.server.MinaServerCom
    at com.company.driver.factory.DeviceTask.execute(DeviceTask.java:54)[321:com.company.dxc.DriverHarness:1.10.1.GA]
    at com.company.task.CycleTaskHarness.run(CycleTaskHarness.java:88)[312:com.company.dxc.TaskRunner:1.10.1.GA]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)[:1.8.0_161]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.company.drvs.sdk.mina.com.server.types.MinaServerComImpl cannot be cast to com.company.drvs.sdk.mina.com.server.MinaServerCom
    at com.company.drvs.sdk.mina.com.server.types.parser.HL7MinaServerParserControllerBase.parse(HL7MinaServerParserControllerBase.java:43)[411:com.company.drvs.sdk.company-sdk-mina-support-hl7:5.20.0]
    at com.company.drvs.welchallyn.nce.parser.NCEParserController.getResult(NCEParserController.java:57)[412:com.company.drvs.welchallyn-nce.core:1.0.1]
    at com.company.drvs.welchallyn.nce.parser.NCEParserController.parse(NCEParserController.java:45)[412:com.company.drvs.welchallyn-nce.core:1.0.1]
    at com.company.drvs.welchallyn.nce.driver.Driver.execute(Driver.java:67)[412:com.company.drvs.welchallyn-nce.core:1.0.1]
    at com.company.driver.factory.DeviceTask.execute(DeviceTask.java:46)[321:com.company.dxc.DriverHarness:1.10.1.GA]
    ... 2 more
```

company-sdk-mina-support-hl7:5.20.0 is the Mentioned Bundle A.

MinaServerComImpl and MinaServerCom are implementations and interface in Bundle B.

The error is happening in this line

```
commObject.initObject((MinaServerCom) getDeviceCom(), deviceMessageEnvelope, getParser());
```

MinsServerComImpl is injected through spring and getDeviceCom() returns the instance of MinaServerComImpl.

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ClassCast Exception in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7764769/classcast-exception-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

The usual cause of this is having multiple definitions of the same class(es).

In Java, the identity of a class is the combination of its fully-qualified name **AND** the `ClassLoader` that defined it. If two classloaders define a class -- even using the same class data in terms of bytes on the disk -- they will be considered different classes in the JVM. Any subclass that inherits from one of those class definitions will not be considered a subtype of the other definition.

In your case it is likely that you have copied the `MinaServerCom` class in multiple bundles. Instead ensure that the definition is in only one bundle, from where its package should be exported. Other bundles should import that package.

Comment: MinaServerCom interface is only in one bundle. But I have multiple versions of that bundle in my karaf. So, do I have to export that package in both the bundles (of different versions)? Thanks for your help. Neil Bartlett.

Comment: Multiple versions of the bundle means that you do have multiple exports of the package. You need to make sure that both the bundle where your `MinaServerComImpl` class is instantiated AND the bundle that receives that object and tries to cast it to `MinaServerCom` import the package containing `MinaServerCom` from the same place. Make sure that your exported package is versioned and that the imports have proper version ranges.

Answer (score 0):

`ClassCastException` came due to any object of one class cannot convert to the another one only because they are not in relationship 'parent-child'.

As you said.. Problem with this line..

```
commObject.initObject((MinaServerCom) getDeviceCom(), deviceMessageEnvelope, getParser());
```

Here `getDeviceCom()` returns the object of  `MinsServerComImpl` and you try to cast it into `MinaServerCom`. then please make sure is there any `Is-A` relationship in between these two class.

It should be either

```
class MinsServerComImpl extends MinaServerCom
```

or

```
class MinsServerComImpl implements MinaServerCom
```

Comment: The MinaServerComImpl does implement MinaServerCom. The issue is OSGI related. When I delete data folder and restart the karaf container.No ClassCastException is thrown. Thanks.